# "Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions" (ext4)

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, steam, fstab

The relevant partition is `ext4` and has my other operating system Arch Linux on it. I've tried so many different `fstab` configurations, but I just can't get Steam to accept it. Here's the relevant line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/df502a85-859d-4fe6-9331-c3c65e7ae406 /mnt/arch auto auto,users,exec 0 0
```

I've also tried changing the user permissions of `/mnt/arch` so that my user can read and write, but no dice. Any idea?

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I can mount the partition just fine, no errors.

Only Steam gives me the error (in the title) when I try to add the drive's Steam library (`/mnt/arch/home/[me]/.local/share/Steam/`) as an additional Steam library folder in Steam on Ubuntu (Steam > Settings > Downloads > Steam Library Folders > Add Library Folder).

Comment: Is this a question about SteamOS? If not, could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you’re running and any error messages that might be reported when trying to mount?

Comment: @matigo, edited.

Comment: I use a .steam link to another partition, mounted with just "defaults", and make the home dir .steam a link to that.  The remove location shows up in the steam library..., even though I never explicitly added it.

Comment: Well, in the process of troubleshooting I used `chown` on the entire Arch partition without thinking, and ended up reinstalling Arch. Haven't yet got back into Ubuntu. I'll update this later.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it was a permissions issue that was resolved with the reinstall, or if it was an issue with fstab, but here is the line I now have.

`/dev/disk/by-uuid/29ff2754-f9c2-492f-b539-9390d9a457e9 /mnt/arch auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,exec 0 0`